# Should I expect changes in my predicted probabilities when increasing the number of categories I am predicting membership in?

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I calculated the predicted probability of membership in group A and not A with binary logistic regression.  Then I broke the not A category into two distinct buckets of which it is comprised - B , C. I then used multinomial logistic regression to calculate the predicted probabilities of membership in A, B, C.

These two different predictions showed some variation in my probabilities.

| Category | Binary Log.Prob | Revised Categories | Multinomial Log. Prob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 74% | A (same as orig) | 67% |
| Not A | 26% | B (B + C = not A) | 12% |
|  |  | C | 21% |

For example the estimate of A changed from 74% to 67% and the not A estimation changed from 26% to 33% (B + C).  Is this expected? And what might account for these differences?

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. The either of the B or C categories might look more or less like A than the combined BC category. In that case, the model might be more or less willing to predict high probabilities of A, since there is a greater or lesser chance of being B or C.